# 'Global' modal in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm building an app in React native, and basically, I need a modal(which will have the same content every time) to be available globally (in all components of app), so that I can be able to open it from anywhere in my app.
Obviously copy/pasting the same modal in all the components is not a good solution
Right now I'm having tons of trouble implementing it, so I would like to know what would be the best way to accomplish something like that

Comment: Have you tried googling? there are few `modals`: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal, https://github.com/bodyflex/react-native-simple-modal, etc.

Comment: I do know how to use Modals, my question is: whats the best way to have one modal available thru all of my app, so for example, if I'm at 'Home' and then go to 'Settings', I would still be able to open that modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Navigator and place your modal below it. Make it visible only when the state changes. The state can be changed from each component inside the Navigator via props.navigator.
You can see the full code with explanation here http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-easy-overlay-modal-with-navigator/